# Delegate methods for instance of object, not all objects of the class

Tags: ruby

Is there a way to delegate methods from an arbitrary object to an arbitrary object? That is, I don't want to delegate methods in the class definition, I want to delegate them for a specific instance of an object without redefining its class. For example...

Consider this class:

```
class ClownHash
    def keys
        return ['Bozo', 'Krusty', 'Pagliacci']
    end
end
```

So I instantiate ClownHash:

```
clowns = ClownHash.new()
```

Now here's the part I can't figure out. Suppose I want to delegate the keys
method to a plain old hash object:

```
hsh = {}
# your answer here
puts hsh.keys
```

which outputs

```
Bozo
Krusty
Pagliacci
```

I know I could do it by redefining the keys method for that hash object, but I'm
ultimately looking to delegate most of the hash methods, so I'm hoping to avoid doing a long redefining routine for every hash every time.

Comment: Is inheritance from Hash an option?

Comment: @spickermann No, I'm doing some heavy duty monkeypatching. The hash object needs to stay a hash object. I'm gutting its methods like an alien taking over a person's mind.

Comment: Any reason you can't use [`Delegator`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/delegate/rdoc/Delegator.html) from the standard library? Or inherit from `BasicObject` and manually forward everything using `method_missing`.

Comment: What's going to happen is that the function accepts a hash as an argument. The function then monkeypatches the hash so that most of its methods do something else, but still return values as if it were a normal hash. But it's crucial that the hash object is still in use --  the function does not return anything, it just changes the input hash. It's sort of a business requirement.

Comment: Anyway, this is really just a golf question. I've had no difficulty redefining the hash's methods - it just seems like there should be a cleaner way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Object#extend`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Object.html#method-i-extend) with a module to add the methods from the module to the object. This will also replace existing methods.

```
module ClownHash
  def keys
    ['Bozo', 'Krusty', 'Pagliacci']
  end

  def clownize
    keys.map(&:reverse)
  end
end

{ foo: 1, bar: 2 }.extend(ClownHash).keys
# => ["Bozo", "Krusty", "Pagliacci"]

{}.extend(ClownHash).clownize
# => ["ozoB", "ytsurK", "iccailgaP"]
```